# Need zuul auth server working example

Tags: authentication, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have working netflix services (data service, gateway, eureka) i.e.
I want to implement auth server, who will provide "user" mongo CRUD, and token verification, which will be before zuul.

could somebody give little working example of 
zuul bootstrap.yml, application.properties
auth bootstrap.yml, application.properties
auth module
and how I can test it, create new user in mongo - authorize with it and get token to provide it to UI app.

and requirement changes in data-service

my working example
https://github.com/mikesockor/repoforSOFquestion

Comment: https://github.com/azizkhani/PiggyMetrics

Comment: can i ask here questions step-by-step?

could you write a few working REST call on your solution?

how to login, get token and do resource call